# Perl script does not print <STDIN> multiple times

Tags: bash, perl

I've got this Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print <STDIN>, "\n";
print <STDIN>, "\n";
print <STDIN>, "\n";
print <STDIN>, "\n";
print <STDIN>, "\n";
```

And I'm passing "Hello" to the script's standard input:

```
echo "Hello" | perl test.pl
```

I'm expecting it to print "Hello" five times, but it just prints "Hello" followed by five newline characters.  Can anyone explain why this wouldn't work as intended?

Comment: <STDIN> in perl is a file descriptor and can be read only once for each standard input.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess it would make more sense to assign `<STDIN>` to a scalar variable then.  How come I can't read this more than once?

Comment: That's how pipes work. After you read it, it's not there any more. Actually that's how files in general work - they have an end, and when you hit the end, repeating the read operation doesn't jump back to the beginning, even on files that do have the ability to go back. What language do you know of where you can read the same input repeatedly just by saying "read" again?

Comment: It's more intuitive *to me* that the value represented by `<STDIN>` is held somewhere in memory once it's piped into the script - it's not like once I read a file it disappears forever.  In any case, please post this as the answer so I can mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: @KaushikNayak `STDIN` refers is a bareword filehandle, not a descriptor. `<STDIN>` is `readline(STDIN)`, and that is not a descriptor either.

Comment: @Sinan. Thanks !. It was good learning great Perl stuff from you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> print <STDIN>, "\n";
> ```

`<STDIN>` (i.e. [`readline(STDIN)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)) "in list context reads until end-of-file is reached and returns a list of lines."

In your program, the first `print` therefore prints ***all*** the lines read from `STDIN`.

By definition, there are no more lines coming from `STDIN`, because `<STDIN>` in list context read everything there was to read.

If you want to read five consecutive lines from `STDIN` and print them, you need:

```
print scalar <STDIN>;
print scalar <STDIN>;
print scalar <STDIN>;
print scalar <STDIN>;
print scalar <STDIN>;
```

By definition, a line ends with a newline. If you do not remove it, there is no need to tack on another.

> It's more intuitive to *me* that the value represented by `<STDIN>` is held somewhere in memory once it's piped into the script

Your program contains no instructions to store the input read from `STDIN`. All it does is to read everything available on `STDIN`, print all of it, and discard it.

If you wanted to store everything you read from `STDIN`, you have to explicitly do so. That's how computer programs work: They do exactly as they are told. Imagine what a disaster it would be if computer programs did different things depending on the intuition of the person writing or running them.

Of course, the data coming from `STDIN` might be unbounded. In that case, storing all of it somewhere is not going to be practical.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense - I wasn't aware that `<STDIN>` was an alias for `readline(STDIN)`.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to loop printing your text an user defined number of times,
you can use a do while loop like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#Program: stdin.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say'; # like print but automatic ending newline.

my $i = 1; # Our incrementer.
my $input; # Our text from standard input that we want to loop.
my $total; # How many times we want to print the text on a loop.

say "Please provide the desired text of your standard input.";
chomp($input = <STDIN>); # chomp removes a newline from the standard input. 
say "Please provide the amount of times that you want to print your standard input to the screen.";
chomp($total = <STDIN>);
say ">>> I'm in your loop! <<<"; 
do # A do while loop iterates at least once and up to the total number of iterations provided by user. 
{
say "Iteration $i of text: $input";
$i++;
}while($i <= $total);
say ">>> I'm out of your loop! <<<";
```

This is what I get when I execute the code with "Hello", and "8" from standard input:

```
> perl .\stdin.pl
Please provide the desired text of your standard input.
Hello!
Please provide the amount of times that you want to print your standard input to the screen.
8
>>> I'm in your loop! <<<
Iteration 1 of text: Hello!
Iteration 2 of text: Hello!
Iteration 3 of text: Hello!
Iteration 4 of text: Hello!
Iteration 5 of text: Hello!
Iteration 6 of text: Hello!
Iteration 7 of text: Hello!
Iteration 8 of text: Hello!
>>> I'm out of your loop! <<<
```

Comment: This doesn't address my question - I wasn't asking for an alternative, I was asking why the code I wrote doesn't work.